# Forms Dialog empty in editor after reusing source in another project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, windows-forms-designer

I created a project with a Windows-Forms GUI (Dialog window) in one project. 
The GUI can be displayed and modified in the winforms designer without problems. When I doubleclick Form1.cs, the dialog comes up in the designer view and I can work on the design.

Then I created a new project and copied the sources for the GUI from the old project. That means, I copied the 3 files Form1.cs, Form1.Designer.cs and Form1.resx

[image]

from the old project folder to the new one and added them to the new project.

Now I can build and run the new project without problems and the dialog shows up as expected when I run it, but in the windows-forms editor in Visual Studio I only see an empty dialog without all the controls. Also the files are now displayed like this, as if VS doesn't recognize that Form1.Designer.cs belongs to Form1:

[image]

So the question is, what am I missing?

Can't be much, as bulding and running is no problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add `DependentUpon` manually in the project file, so it looks something like this:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Form1.cs">
      <SubType>Form</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Form1.Designer.cs">
      <DependentUpon>Form1.cs</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Form1.resx">
      <DependentUpon>Form1.cs</DependentUpon>
    </EmbeddedResource>
```